# Populating multiple text fields based on a combo box

Tags: ms-access

What I am trying to do is populate text fields based on what a user selects in a combo box. The problem I'm running into is the text fields need data from multiple queries. One text box per query and in total there are 6. So the me.txtTextBox1 = me.cboComboBox1.column(1) will not work. This is probably a very simple fix but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I read your question a couple of times and your intent is still not clear at all. Please elaborate and provide examples of current and desired situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need an *Event Procedure* for the **AfterUpdate** event of you combo box. In that procedure, you could use 6 statements using the `DLookup` function, but that function is very slow. Therefore, I suggest to open 6 recordsets that return (at most) one record to retrieve the values for the 6 textboxes. When using 6 parameterized queries, the code could look like this:

```
Private Sub cboComboBox1_AfterUpdate()

    With CurrentDb

        Me.txtTextBox1 = Null
        With .QueryDefs("qryQuery1")
            !ParameterNameInQuery1 = Me.cboComboBox1
            With .OpenRecordset()
                If Not .EOF Then
                    Me.txtTextBox1 = !NameOfFieldInQuery1
                End If
                .Close
            End With
            .Close
        End With

        ' ... other 5 code Fragments for the other 5 textboxes ...

    End With

End Sub
```